# Array with a single String getting automatically and undesireably converted to just a String

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

In my CasperJS script when I pass an array to my function through the evaluate function it may have 1 or more strings. It works as expected when there are multiple strings, but when the array only has 1 string it behaves really oddly. If I pass an array with a single string inside, it becomes just the string. Where am I going wrong?

My CasperJS script:

```
function myFunction(input) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(input));
}

//allow console logs through for debugging
casper.on('remote.message', function(message) {
  this.echo(message);
});

//get my page
casper.start(...);

//attempt to call myFunction with an array as input
casper.then(function() {
  var input = ['#someId'];
  this.evaluate(myFunction, input); 
});
```

Desired Output:

```
["#someId"]
```

Actual Output:

```
"#someId"
```

Output if var input = ['#firstId', '#secondId']

```
["#firstId", "#secondId"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is precisely what CasperJS adds when it has exactly two arguments: function and function argument. It will try to "unpack" the one argument that you pass if it is an array or object according to [this](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/1.1-beta3/modules/casper.js#L701-L708):

```
Casper.prototype.evaluate = function evaluate(fn, context) {
    ...
    // function context
    if (arguments.length === 1) {
        return utils.clone(this.page.evaluate(fn));
    } else if (arguments.length === 2) {
        // check for closure signature if it matches context
        if (utils.isObject(context) && eval(fn).length === Object.keys(context).length) {
            context = utils.objectValues(context);
        } else {
            context = [context];
        }
    } else {
        // phantomjs-style signature
        context = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
    }
    return utils.clone(this.page.evaluate.apply(this.page, [fn].concat(context)));
};
```

This leads to interesting behavior like the following complete script shows:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.on("remote.message", function(msg) {
    this.echo("Console: " + msg);
});

casper.start('http://example.com/').then(function(){
    var arr = ['#someId'];
    var arrm = ['#someId', '#someOtherId'];
    var obj = {a:'#someId'};
    var objm = {a:'#someId', b:'#someOtherId'};

    this.echo("1");
    this.evaluate(function(arr) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
    }, arr);

    this.echo("2");
    this.evaluate(function(arr) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
    }, arrm);

    this.echo("3");
    this.evaluate(function(obj) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
    }, obj);

    this.echo("4");
    this.evaluate(function(obj) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
    }, objm);

    this.echo("5");
    this.evaluate(function(arr, obj) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
    }, arr, obj);

    this.echo("6");
    this.evaluate(function(a) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
    }, obj);

    this.echo("7");
    this.evaluate(function(b) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(b));
    }, objm);

    this.echo("8");
    this.evaluate(function(a, b) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(b));
    }, objm);

    this.echo("9");
    this.evaluate(function(b, a) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(b));
    }, objm);
}).run();
```

Output:

```
1
Console: "#someId"
2
Console: ["#someId","#someOtherId"]
3
Console: "#someId"
4
Console: {"a":"#someId","b":"#someOtherId"}
5
Console: ["#someId"]
Console: {"a":"#someId"}
6
Console: "#someId"
7
Console: {"a":"#someId","b":"#someOtherId"}
8
Console: "#someId"
Console: "#someOtherId"
9
Console: "#someOtherId"
Console: "#someId"
```

Note that an object is unpacked to the `evaluate()` callback arguments by name if the keys of the object match (see tests 8 and 9).

PhantomJS itself doesn't do any kind of unpacking. This is all CasperJS.

Comment: how do you recommend achieving the desired behavior then when you  have an array of only 1 string?

Comment: You could pack it an object. Perhaps this is the reason why some people prefer to always write `this.evaluate(function(a){...}, {a: someVariable})` instead of `this.evaluate(function(a){...}, someVariable)`.